# bucle en java no funciona

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean cond=true;
        int x=0;
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero mayor que 0 (0 finaliza):");
        x= sc.nextInt();
        while(x>0 cond=true);{
        if(x%2==0 &&(x>0));
        System.out.println("El numero es par y positivo y su cuadrado es:"+x*x);        
         if(x<0); 
         cond=false;
```

hola , el programa no hace nada cuando le introduces un numero y no se porque es

Comment: Hola! Ese código está incompleto, faltan llaves de cierre, sobran algunas otras cosas... en general sospecho que no compila. Algún error al ejecutar el código?

Comment: esto tiene un error de sintaxis aca: while(x>0 cond=true)... obviamente ni compila... o lo copiaste mal...

Comment: hola @junior12 bienvenido a es.SO! Te aconsejo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) asi podemos tenerlo claro todos y ayudarte con tu problema

Answer (score 1):

tu código tiene varios errores.
Por ejemplo, en este fragmento:

```
while(x>0 cond=true);{
```

La forma correcta de declarar un `while` es de la siguiente manera:

```
while(condicion){
//codigo a realizar
}
```

Si te fijas, aquí no lleva un `;` despues del paréntesis.
Supongo que aquí lo que quieres evaluar es `Mientras` X sea mayor a 0 `Y` condicion sea igual a verdadero.
De ser así, esto quedaría así (ya sin el ;):

```
while(x > 0 && cond=true){
```

Ahora vamos con el `if`
Tu lo tienes así:

```
if(x%2==0 &&(x>0));
```

Al igual que con el `while`, tienes un problema a la hora de estructurarlo.
La sentencia `IF` se usa así:

```
if(condicion){
//codigo a realizar
}
```

En tu caso, debes quitar el `;` y agregar las llaves.

y lo mismo con tu otro `IF`:

```
if(x<0);
```

Debe quedar así:

```
if(x<0){
//codigo
}
```

Ahora. Te faltan varias llaves, y la lógica está mal. Tu pides un numero, y lo evaluas. Si es mayor a cero, entonces entra al ciclo while. Pero en ningún momento ese numero cambia, por lo que será un ciclo infinito.

Te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int x=0;
        System.out.print("Ingrese un numero mayor que 0");
        //pedimos un numero y lo guardamos en x
        x= sc.nextInt();
       //si el numero es mayor a 0, entramos:
        if(x>0){
         //Comprobamos si el numero es par
         if(x%2==0){
         //si es par, mostramos estp
          System.out.println("El numero es par y positivo y su cuadrado es:"+x*x);
         }else{
         //si no es par, se muestra esto
         System.out.println("El numero no es par");
         }
        }else{
        //si el numero no es mayor a 0, mostramos esto.
        System.out.println("El numero ingresado es invalido");
        }
```

Parece que apenas vas empezando en esto de la programación , así que te invito a que te esfuerces un poquito más a la hora de investigar y de tratar de resolver tus problemas. Si no me equivoco, tu eres la misma persona que antes había pedido directamente que le hicieran el código. Básicamente fue lo que yo hice aquí, pero bueno, al menos estoy tratando de que entiendas en donde estabas equivocado, y lo más importante, POR QUÉ estabas equivocado. Espero que te haya servido!

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: si la respuesta te ayudó, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que a otras personas que tengan tu problema también les ayude, también se agradecen los votos positivos. Saludos!